# Identifying the values which have the maximum number of keys

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

I have a dict which goes something like this:

```
 ip = { "1" : ['a','b'],
      "2" : ['a','c'],
      "3" : ['a','b','c','d'],
      "4" : ['a','b','d','e']}
```

I need to find which of the items in the value sets have maximum number of keys against them and also have the items listed in descending order. The output will be something like :

```
op = {"a":4,"b":3,"c":2,"d":2,"e":1}
```

But I read somewhere that the dict cannot be in a sorted fashion, so the output can be a tuple too:

```
op = [('a', 4), ('b', 3), ('c', 2), ('d', 2), ('e', 1)]
```

We can iterate through the dict and for each of the items in the value set increment the result in a `defaultdict` for that item.

```
op = defaultdict(int)
for k,v in ip.iteritems():
    for item in v:
        op[item]+=1
op = sorted(op.items(), key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
```

Is there a quicker/better way of doing this than the nested for?

Comment: Can you provide your expected output for the example?

Comment: added the desired output..

Comment: There is such a thing as an ordered dictionary... `from collections import OrderedDict`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply use `Counter` and `chain.from_iterable`

```
In [9]: from collections import Counter

In [10]: from itertools import chain

In [11]: ip = { "1" : ['a','b'],
    ...:       "2" : ['a','c'],
    ...:       "3" : ['a','b','c','d'],
    ...:       "4" : ['a','b','d','e']}

In [12]: Counter(chain.from_iterable(ip.values()))
Out[12]: Counter({'a': 4, 'b': 3, 'c': 2, 'd': 2, 'e': 1})
```

To remove duplicate value you can always do something like this:

```
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> sorted(Counter(chain.from_iterable(map(set, ip.values()))).items(), key=itemgetter(1), reverse=True)
[('a', 4), ('b', 3), ('c', 2), ('d', 2), ('e', 1)]
```

Answer (score 0):

This here is not correct:

```
sorted(op.items(), key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
```

Try instead:

```
sorted(ip, key=lambda elementInDict: len(ip[elementInDict]), reverse=True)
```

**example:**

```
for elementInDict in sorted(ip, key=lambda elementInDict: len(ip[elementInDict]), reverse=True):
    print elementInDict,
```